# ValueError while enumerating list

Tags: python, valueerror, enumerate

I am trying to add index number in front of the list using enumerate with the following code:

```
buttons = [('John', 'Sen', 'Morro'), ('Lin', 'Ajay', 'Filip')] 
for first, second, third in enumerate(buttons):
    print(first, second, third)
```

I am getting following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

>
```

I want the following output:

```
0 ('John', 'Sen', 'Morro')
1 ('Lin', 'Ajay', 'Filip')
```

Answer (score 1):

Unpack the index and the values separately.

```py
for index, (first, second, third) in enumerate(buttons):
    print(index, first, second, third)
```

You don't need to unpack each element of the original list if you're not going to access their values anyway.

```py
for index, value in enumerate(buttons):
    print(index, value)
```